# Why is table1.Date = table2.Date - 1 different from table1.date = table2.date - Interval 1 day in my sql

Tags: mysql

Problem

> The table contains information about the temperature on a certain day.
> id is the primary key for this table.
> **Columns (id, record date, temperature)**
>
> Write an SQL query to find all dates' Id with higher temperatures compared to its previous dates (yesterday).
>
> Return the result table in any order.

My Query :

```sql
SELECT w1.id AS Id
FROM weather AS w 
INNER JOIN weather AS w1 ON w.recorddate = w1.recorddate - 1
WHERE w1.temperature > w.temperature;
```

Alternate Query:

```sql
SELECT w1.id AS Id
FROM weather AS w 
INNER JOIN weather AS w1 ON w.recorddate = w1.recorddate - Interval 1 day
WHERE w1.temperature > w.temperature;
```

My Query is not giving same results as the alternate query

Answer (score 0):

The 2 expressions return the new date in different formats. In your queries there is an implicit conversion and the result should be the same, as in the following example.
If this is causing errors you would do better to stick to `recorddate - Interval 1 day`. The following query shows the difference between the 2 formats.

> ```
> select
> id,
> temperature,
> recorddate,
> recorddate - 1,
> recorddate - Interval 1 day
> from weather;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | temperature | recorddate | recorddate - 1 | recorddate - Interval 1 day
> -: | ----------: | :--------- | -------------: | :--------------------------
>  1 |          15 | 2022-04-27 |       20220426 | 2022-04-26                 
>  2 |          18 | 2022-04-28 |       20220427 | 2022-04-27
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=011892aaa59b547615b34c18424ad1e9)*